# Autodesk Forge Structural Column Length

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am using Model Derivative API to retrieve REVIT model properties.

When getting properties of Structural Columns, I do not find "Length" of the Structural Column. Only Base and Top Level (= Level Name) and Base and Level Offset (= Offset from that Level Name). I could calculate the length if I knew the Level for each "Level Name" but the properties do not retrieve Levels...

1. Any ideas how to get Column Length? In Revit it is an exposed property under Schedules, but not in Forge Viewer...
2. Any ideas hot to get the levels of each "Level"?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding #1: the Model Derivative service typically tries to export the "most important" metadata to prevent the output file size from exploding (which would impact the loading and preview experience as well). If there's some specific metadata that is missing that you need, you could consider using the [Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/overview/) service to run your custom Revit API plugin in the cloud extracting all the information you need.

Regarding #2: for Revit designs the Model Derivative service outputs one more dataset called "AEC Model Data" which includes AEC specific information incl. levels. You can learn more about this feature in https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/consume-aec-data-which-are-model-derivative-api.